# Storing data on device

Tags: c++

I have not many experience with operations/storage of binary data so I would greatly appreciate if someone could clarify some things for me.

I have a device say where you *have to* store 16 bytes. e.g., you should send it an array of bytes proceeded probably with header information. e.g., smth like this:

```
unsigned char sendBuffer[255];
sendBuffer[0] = headerInfo1;
sendBuffer[1] = headerInfo1;
sendBuffer[2] = headerInfo1;
sendBuffer[3] = headerInfo1;
sendBuffer[4] = data;
sendBuffer[5] = data;
sendBuffer[6] = data;
sendBuffer[7] = data;
sendBuffer[8] = data;
...
sendBuffer[20] = data;
```

Let's say send operation is easy, you just use `Send(sendBuffer, length)`.

My question is say I want to store an **integer** in the device - what is the best way to do this?

I have a sample code which does it and I was not sure if it was ok and how it was doing it. It confused me too. I basically enter the number I want to store in text box. Say I want to store `105` in decimal. I enter `"00000000000000000000000000000105"` (I am not sure how program interprets this yet, as decimal or as hex), then there is this code:

```
for(int i=0,m=0; i < size; i+=2,m++)
{
char ch1, ch2;
ch1=(char)str[i]; // str contains the number I entered above as string, padded
ch2=(char)str[i+1];
int dig1, dig2;
if(isdigit(ch1)) dig1 = ch1 - '0';
else if(ch1>='A' && ch1<='F') dig1 = ch1 - 'A' + 10;
else if(ch1>='a' && ch1<='f') dig1 = ch1 - 'a' + 10;
if(isdigit(ch2)) dig2 = ch2 - '0';
else if(ch2>='A' && ch2<='F') dig2 = ch2 - 'A' + 10;
else if(ch2>='a' && ch2<='f') dig2 = ch2 - 'a' + 10;

// Contains data to write as a byte array; this is basically the 'data' part as mentioned in my above snippet
array1[m] = (char)(dig1*16 + dig2);
}
```

And  this `array1[m]` is written to the device using `Send` as above. But when I debug `array1` contains: `0000000000000015`

When I do the read the value I get is correct, it is `00000000000000000000000000000105`. How come this works?

Comment: What is the purpose of that code?  Why don't you just convert the string to an `int`, and then store that?  Or just truncate the string, and store that?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: Ok I found out one more detail. The text box I mentioned above -- seems to restrict the user to enter ONLY hex values. (This code is part of routine which writes data to device in the manner I mentioned in my post, e.g., `Send`)

Comment: I'm a little confused too. You are saying that the code above works as you want? And basically you just want an explanation of how it works? That's what you seem to be asking to me, but I would have thought it's fairly obvious how the code works. So I think you should explain a little about what is confusing you. I would guess it's about the different ways of representing and displaying integers.

Comment: @john: Yes, john first let's just start with the text box I mentioned. That text box as I understood forces user to enter exactly 16 bytes in HEX mode only. So afterwards that code is executed. What it does I think now, is that it basically converts the HEX data as byte array am I right? (because if I enter "00000000000000000000000000000211" in the text box - the byte array `array1` contains actually "00000000000000217")

Comment: The text box lets you enter text (as hexadecimal digits). The code is a text to binary conversion. What you end up with is a binary form of the number you entered as text. (But no way is 217 a binary representation of 211, that's either a typo or something is wrong).

Comment: @john: yes but it works, when read, I think also the data written in device is converted back to hex ... (note the `0..0217` string is shorter above than the one for 211)

Comment: @john: I think I am getting what is happening, when I type `00000000000000000000000000000211` in text box, it is read like this: `02` is read separately(as hex) - and `11` is read separately (as hex). Do you see? 02 in binary is `0010` and 11 hex in binary is `10001`. This is why debugger shows **217** - it is also shown separately. 2 is from hex two and 17 is because `10001` in binary is 17 in decimal. Do you get it? What you think?

Comment: @dmcr_code. That makes sense. Your debugger may have an option to display values in hexadecimal.

Answer (score 0):

You're reinventig a few wheels here, but that's to be expected if you're new to C++.

`std::cin >> yourInteger` will read an integer, no need to convert that yourself.

Leading zeroes are usually not written out, but in a C++ integer type they're always present. E.g. `int32_t` always has 32 bits. If it stores 105 (0x69), it really stores 0x00000069.

So, the best way is probably to `memcpy` that integer to your `sendBuffer`. You should copy `sizeof(yourInteger)` bytes.

Comment: hm... I see so you suggest if I have `int x` (which is say 4 bytes). I use memcpy(data, x, size) - where data is `byte array`. And it will correctly "embed" my 4 byte value `x` in the byte array `data` right?

Comment: @dmcr_code If you copy in this way you have to be aware of *endianness*. This solution may or may not do what you want depending on the endianess of your platform and the endianess of your target device. If they are not the same then this will not work. But try it and see.

Comment: @dmcr_code The other issue with this technique is that it will not deal with integers bigger than than the maximum integer size of your platform. No platform that I know of has 16 byte integers, this technique will not work if you need to deal with integers that big.

Comment: Hmm.. I see. No MSalters the 16 bytes is requirement there but the int actually stored there will not be that big

Comment: @john: But in that case, you'd just use an `int32_t[4]`. Or whatever other representation is reasonable for your application. 16 byte integers are virtually never needed.

Comment: @MSalters OK, but if you use int32_t[4] then you have to chop the input text into four pieces before converting each piece to an int32_t and then doing the memcpy. Plus you still have the potential endianess issue. I think the current code is simpler.

Comment: @john: Fair point about endianness, use an `uint_8[16]` instead. Chopping a hex string of 32 characters into 16x2 chars isn't a real problem.

Comment: I think I can't follow you anymore, i.e., not quite getting what you mean (john and MSalters) ..

Answer (score 0):

Seems there are a few questions hiding in here, so some extra answers:

You say that `array1` contains: 0000000000000015, not `105`.

Well, it's an array, and each member is shown as an 8 bits integer in its own right.
E.g. the last value is 5 or 05, that's the same after all. Similarly, the penultimate integer is 1 or 01.

You also wrote "Say I want to store 105 in decimal. I enter `00000000000000000000000000000105`". That doesn't actually store 105 decimal. It stores 105 hexadecimal, which is 261 decimal. It is the string to integer conversion which determines the final value. If you would use base 18 (octodecimal), the string "105" becomes the integer 1*18*18 + 0 + 5 = 329 (decimal), and that would be stored as 000000101001001 binary.

Comment: I think I started following what it is. Look at it. I say I entered: `00000000000000000000000000000105` - but this is interpreted as HEX. 105hex in binary is: `"100000101"`. Then I said `array1` is "0000000000000015" not `105` right. But yes, if we look at 1 and 5 separately and convert them to binary, we get `0001` and `0101` -- now it starts to look at little bit like binary representation of hex number 105 isn't it?

Comment: @dmcr_code: Just in case you didn't realize it: hex is base 16, which is 2*2*2*2. Therefore, every hex digit converts to exactly 4 bits, and you can convert each digit in isolation (without overflow). This is not the case for decimal.

Comment: Ok MSalters, I think I knew I can convert each digit in isolation. But does it make sense to you that when I entered 105 in hex in my text box the `array1` contains `0000000000000015` and not `00000000000000105`?

Comment: MSalters: dear MSalters can you answer if it makes sense to you that when I entered 105 in hex in my text box the `array1` contains `0000000000000015` and not `00000000000000105`

Comment: please see my last response to john, I think I got that point right?? Thank you.

Comment: @dmcr_code: Yup. The problem really is your debugger. If it showed the array contents as `0,0,0,0,1,5` you'd be a bit wiser. I'd suggest you enter `7B7B7B7B7B7B7B7B` as a number in the textbox, and look at the array in the debugger.